# Dynamic selection of layer in QGIS atlas

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I am making an atlas where I want to expose features with specific values. A good way to illustrate this could be this real estate database:

```
01 estate_a expensive yellowhouse
02 estate_b expensive yellowhouse
03 estate_c cheap     greenhouse
04 estate_d cheap     brownhouse
05 estate_e expensive greenhouse
```

The current atlas functionality in QGIS (2.18.0) supports making an atlas with one map for each estate. I want to make one map with all expensive estates and one with all cheap estates. Is this possible?

Also - can I have different symbols according to different house colors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a coverage layer where all expensive estates are merged and all cheap extents are merged so you have only 2 features - make sure you have an attribute called "estate_type" and fill that with expensive or cheap.

Then in the symbol properties of your estate layers change the symbol to rule based.

Add a rule like below

```
 attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  attribute(  @atlas_feature , 'estate_type')
```

If the atlas is on the 'cheap' feature in the coverage layer it will symbolise all the cheap estates; when you change to the 'expensive' feature in the coverage layer it will symbolise all the expensive ones.[image]

In your question you also want to symbolise the houses differently according to a color attribute. You can maintain any styling. Just choose your favourite symbolising and symbolize. After this you change to Rule-based styling and add the string before all rules. Your rules et will then look like this:

```
attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  attribute(  @atlas_feature , 'estate_type') AND "housecolor" = 'yellowhouse'
attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  attribute(  @atlas_feature , 'estate_type') AND "housecolor" = 'greenhouse'
attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  attribute(  @atlas_feature , 'estate_type') AND "housecolor" = 'brownhouse'
```

The above figure is an example of how I use it. I have an ELSE rule to symbolise all other features that aren't part of my coverage layer. Leave this out if you don't want them visible.

Comment: This works well for presenting all estates in an equal way. What if I want to identify the objects by their object number, or if say, the objects had different colors and I wanted to indicate this in the map?

Comment: Figured it out! The following: 

attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  attribute(  atlas_feature , 'estate_type') AND attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  'expensive'

made it possible to have different colors for different attributes. So if I had different house colors I could probably add that dimension this way:

attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  attribute(  atlas_feature , 'estate_type') AND attribute(  $currentfeature , 'estate_type') =  'expensive' AND attribute(  $currentfeature , 'house_color') =  'Yellow'

(atlas_feature has an @ in front)

Comment: Either create a set of rules and add this rule to it. Or right click and add a category or new rule set nested to this rule

Comment: Implement the added dimension to your answer and I will accept it straight. My question has been updated to support an extended answer.

Comment: Updated the answer with my own experiences. Good answer from @Freight_Train - thankyou!